# opening and parsing a file in c++ to check for punctuation and to convert to lower case using two functions

Tags: c++, string-parsing

I am trying to open a file and parse a file with separate functions.

when i parse the file, i want to read each line in my input file and i want to ignore any punctuation and make everything lowercase so that i can then print it out to a separate file into strings with no spaces or punctuation.

i have tried to implement it but i cannot figure out what i am doing wrong. I am not getting an error but my output is not correct.

this is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <ostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

void processFile();
void parseFile(ifstream&, ofstream&);

int main()
{

    //call function to open file and process
    cout << "processing file" << endl;
    processFile();

    return 0;
}


void processFile()
{
    string newString;
    ifstream inFile;
    ofstream outFile;

    cout << "opening files" << endl;
    // open files
    inFile.open("inFile.txt");
    outFile.open("outFile.txt");

    cout << "parsing file" << endl;
    //parse file for capitalization & punctuation
    parseFile(inFile, outFile);

    //close files
    outFile.close();
    inFile.close();
}

void parseFile(ifstream &inFile, ofstream &outFile)
{
    //create and initialize variables
    string newString;;
    int i = 0;

    if(!inFile)
    {
        cout << "ERROR!!! Cannot read file.";
    }
    else
    {
        do
        {
            //read each line in the input file until EOF
            getline(inFile, newString, '\n');

            //parse each string for punctuation
            while(newString[i])
            {
                if(isalpha(newString[i])) //check each char in each      
                                          //string for punctuation
                {
                    if(isupper(newString[i])) //check each string for 
                                              //capitalization
                    {
                        newString[i] = tolower(newString[i]); //convert 
                                                          //string to 
                                                          //lower case
                    }
                    outFile << newString[i]; //output each line to file
                    cout << newString[i];
                }
                i++;
                if(newString[i] == '\n')
                    break;
            }
        } while(!inFile.eof());
    }
}
```

this is my input:

```
racecar
RACEcar
rotator
rotor
civic
Red rum, sir, is murder!
Rats live on no evil star.
Neil, a trap! Sid is part alien!
Step on no pets.
Dammit, I’m mad!
```

my expected output is everything in the input printed in lowercase, without punctuation and spaces

this is my actual output:

```
racecarsirismurderraliena
```

Comment: This is my output data to outFile.txt:

processing file
opening files
parsing file
racecarsirismurderraliena

Comment: Input, expected output and actual output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to reinitialize i after each call to getline(), otherwise it will continue at the offset where the previous string ended. getline() overwrites newString every time it's called.

```
do
    {
        //read each line in the input file until EOF
        getline(inFile, newString, '\n');
        i = 0;

        //parse each string for punctuation
```

If you compare your input with your output it makes sense.

The first string "racecar" is parsed without problem. Now i is 7.

The next 4 calls to getline() get strings that are shorter than 7 so you get no new output in outFile.txt.

The call to getline() after that gets "Red rum, sir, is murder!", starting from 7 you get "sirismurder" and i is now 24.

The next call to getline() gets "Rats live on no evil star.", starting from 24 you get "r" and i is is now 26

The last call to getline() gets "Neil, a trap! Sid is part alien!", starting from 26 you get "alien".

Answer (score 4):

You will need to initialize `i` after `getline()` . This is because each call of `getline()` will cause each line of data read from input file be overwritten (not appended) to the `newString`.

```
do
{
    //read each line in the input file until EOF
    getline(inFile, newString, '\n');

    i = 0; // <== initialize 'i' to zero

    //parse each string for punctuation
    while(newString[i])
    {
```

Comment: thank you man! i don't understand though. i want it to be over written, how does initializing it before get line() affect my logic... i thought i had this one perfect until that error... thanks again so much

Comment: oh my god i totally understand and thank you!!!!! i wish i had enough rep to upvote your answer!!! every time the get line is called it overwrites newString, so i have to initialize i to 0 after every get line so that i starts off checking each newString at newString[0].... i always mess up in the stupidest places!! frustration occurs now.. lol thanks again!